# Getting and error while building flutter project

Tags: flutter

I am trying to install my flutter app into my device. It was working fine till I added a class named UserDb(model class). It then started giving me the following error:[image: error]

The weird thing is that I have renamed the class to another name and removed any object named userDb but it is still showing me that error. I even removed that model class and all its usage from my project.

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#flutter-installation-corrupted

Comment: I used those commands and they ran successfully but now my lib folder is not showing and and the run icon is greyed out. I am using android studio

Comment: The instructions are not related to the `lib/` directory. I don't know what's going on on your site.

Comment: "The git stash drop command drops customizations you might have made to the Flutter installation.". Is it due to that?  here is the image https://ibb.co/jyt15t6

Comment: Sure, but `lib/` is in your project directory, not in the Flutter install directory.

Comment: Unfortunately  ran those commands inside my project directory and not in the flutter install directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189972/discussion-between-nick-tdr-and-gunter-zochbauer).